# Making a FOREIGN KEY on Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to make a database about countries (for a school assignment)on Access, but Access is saying that there is a syntax error in constraint clause about me using the word REFERENCES- does anyone have any ideas of how to get these FOREIGN KEYs to work? I have been trying to look it up, but to no avail (also just started working with SQL)

```
     Create Table Countries 
    (Country_ID INTEGER primary key,
     name TEXT(255),
     Politics_ID INTEGER                           
       CONSTRAINT fkPoliticsID FOREIGN KEY (Politics_ID) REFERENCES Politics,
     Eduction_ID INTEGER
       CONSTRAINT fkEductionID FOREIGN KEY (Eduction_ID) REFERENCES Eduction,
     Geography_ID INTEGER
        CONSTRAINT fkGeographyID  FOREIGN KEY (Geography_ID) REFERENCES 
        Geography,
     Demographic_ID INTEGER
        CONSTRAINT fkDemographicID  FOREIGN KEY (Demographic_ID) REFERENCES 
        Demographic,
     Economy_ID INTEGER
        CONSTRAINT fkEconomyID  FOREIGN KEY (Economy_ID) REFERENCES Economy
     );
```

[image]

Here is when I added more commas
[image]

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Why do you programmatically create table?

Comment: Review https://sourcedaddy.com/ms-access/foreign-key-constraint.html and https://www.w3schools.com/SQL/sql_ref_foreign_key.asp. Perhaps: `FOREIGN KEY (Politics_ID) REFERENCES`.

Comment: It's for a school project, I added a picture showing the problem for clarification, thanks for the feedback :) I also tried https://www.w3schools (link suggested), but did not fix it (although did help, thanks)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a similar but simpler query which works in Access 2010.

Notice I defined a `Politics_ID` field in the `Countries` table to serve as the foreign key field used to reference the `Politics` table.

```sql
CREATE TABLE Countries
(
    Country_ID INTEGER primary key,
    Country_name TEXT(255),
    Politics_ID INTEGER,
    CONSTRAINT fkPoliticsID FOREIGN KEY (Politics_ID) REFERENCES Politics
);
```

That statement assumes the matching field in the remote table (`Politics`) is also named `Politics_ID`.  However if that remote field has a different name (say `Pol_ID`), you can include its name after the remote table name like this:

```sql
CONSTRAINT fkPoliticsID FOREIGN KEY (Politics_ID) REFERENCES Politics (Pol_ID)
```

Comment: I tried that and it helped, but the problem is still not working

Comment: I added a picture of what is happening now

Comment: Your sample query text and the queries in the 2 screen captures are all different.  If the 3rd version --- the one in the 2nd screen capture --- is the one you're testing, perhaps it will work if you close the `Eduction` table first.  Also close the `Geography` table to avoid a lock failure with that table.